# Limit a Razor View's access to other objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Can one limit the capabilities / which objects a razor view can access somehow? As far as I know it's capable of pretty much anything, and in a big project that's not really what we want. Ultimately we'd only want it to be able to access it's viewmodel. (Like in Liqud/DotLiquid afaiu).

Answer (score 1):

Either implement a pattern of review for this where you specifically are going against a viewmodel or interface etc or pull your views into a separate assembly and therefore they can't call your controllers without an explicit reference.

Comment: I think my question was a bit vague - but the suggestion to put my views in a separate assembly gets close to what I want. Other than that I think it's a limitation of Razor (or mvc3)- not being able to limit the powers of a view.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen many people trying to implement any kind of code analysis, etc... tools trying to prevent developers from doing X or Y. While those automated tools might bring some order there is nothing other than a code review session from an experienced developer and of course if you have the possibility a good training session for your developers prior to coding (obviously the two are not exclusive) that would allow you to ensure that *the rules* are respected in large projects.

Hint:

When I do a code review of an ASP.NET MVC application I start by the <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd> combination and search for forbidden words such as `ViewData`, `ViewBag` inside the application. If more than 0 occurrences are found I start to worry about the quality of the code and the proper usage of view models.